# Getting the domain name making requests to my API endpoints

Tags: node.js, api, express, oauth-2.0

I'm using Node + express to build an API. The idea is to be able to let other developers login and register their app so that i can authorize access to my API endpoints.

```
exports = passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({

    clientID: '999999999',
    clientSecret: '999999999',
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"

},function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    profile.access_token = accessToken;

    db.mongoClient.connect(db.moments, function(err, db){
        var user = db.collection('user');

        user.find({'facebook':profile.id}).toArray(function(err, docs){
            console.log(docs);
        })
    })

    done(null, profile);

}));
```

I have set this up using the [passport facebook strategy](http://passportjs.org/docs/facebook). This allows developers to login to a profile page on my app where they are presented with the access_token i got from facebook. I'm using this access_token to allow a connection between my app and their app using the [bearer token strategy](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-bearer).

However, i also want to add another layer of security. They should register the domain name that is going to make API calls to my app. This should protect me from developers passing along the token to other developers (did i got that part right?).

> The question: How can i check that they are indeed making the request from the registered domain name?

thx,

Answer (score 0):

After your facebook authentication, you know user and you know his registered domain. Then make call from server to some defined script at registered domain. And if indeed it was call from this user then he should return some response which you agreed with him. And if response is ok, then finish authentication (if I correctly remember some payment systems make this verification for online shops).

Or something more sophisticated, after facebook auth, send to registered domain url some temporary token. Then user must send you in next call this temporary token and you exchange it for final token.

To be secure your users should have https when your server call them. Otherwise it is not reliable.